# Xamarin Bluetooth. Show scan in popup menu and connect

Tags: bluetooth, xamarin.android, popupmenu

I'm programing a bluetooth controller for android. I've been able to switch the Bluetooth on and off, but now I need to scan the nearby devices. These I want to display as a popup menu as soon it finished scanning. Then you should click on the device you want and connect with it.

Note that it should connect also to not paired devices.
And the popup menu should be "big" like covering most of the screen... (not like the button-popup only)

```
namespace BluetoothController
{
    [Activity(Label = "BluetoothController", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity, View.IOnTouchListener
    {
        BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter;
        Button button_OnOff, button_Forward, button_Fire, button_Backward, button_Left, button_Right;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Initialize Components
            Initialize();

            // Get local Bluetooth Adapter
            BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            button_OnOff = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button_onoff);
            button_Forward = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button_forward);
            button_Fire = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button_fire);
            button_Backward = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button_backward);
            button_Left = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button_left);
            button_Right = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button_right);
            button_OnOff.SetOnTouchListener(this);
            button_Forward.SetOnTouchListener(this);
            button_Backward.SetOnTouchListener(this);
            button_Left.SetOnTouchListener(this);
            button_Right.SetOnTouchListener(this);
            button_Fire.SetOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        // Event handler for Buttons
        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            // Handle if Buttons is pressed or released
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    // Do if pressed
                    switch (v.Id)
                    {
                        case Resource.Id.button_forward:
                            break;
                        case Resource.Id.button_backward:
                            break;
                        case Resource.Id.button_left:
                            break;
                        case Resource.Id.button_right:
                            break;
                        case Resource.Id.button_fire:
                            break;
                        case Resource.Id.button_onoff:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                    // Do if released
                    switch (v.Id)
                    {
                        case Resource.Id.button_forward:
                            break;
                        case Resource.Id.button_backward:
                            break;
                        case Resource.Id.button_left:
                            break;
                        case Resource.Id.button_right:
                            break;
                        case Resource.Id.button_fire:
                            break;
                        case Resource.Id.button_onoff:
                            if (BTAdapter != null)
                            {
                                if (!BTAdapter.IsEnabled)
                                {
                                    BTAdapter.Enable();
                                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Bluetooth enabled", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

                                    // Display Devices and connect to the clicked one
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    BTAdapter.Disable();
                                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Bluetooth disabled", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.MakeText(this, "Bluetooth not supported", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

After I turn on the Bluetooth in the event handler, it should wait a bit and display the selectable devices... this I did with System.Threading.Thread.sleep()

How can I take the discovered BT-devices and show them on the popup menu?
And how can I choose one of them to connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you recognising bluetooth devices and managing them.

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class AndroidBluetooth : BroadcastReceiver
{


    private static BluetoothDevice _bluetoothDevice;
    private readonly BluetoothAdapter _bluetoothAdapter;
    public BluetoothSocket _bluetoothSocket;
    public readonly IntentFilter _intentFilter;

     public  AndroidBluetooth()
    {

        _bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
        _intentFilter = new IntentFilter();


        _intentFilter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound);
        _intentFilter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionNameChanged);
        _intentFilter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionBondStateChanged);
        _intentFilter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionPairingRequest);
        _intentFilter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclConnected);
        _intentFilter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected);
        _intentFilter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnectRequested);
        _intentFilter.AddAction(BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryStarted);
        _intentFilter.AddAction(BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished);
        _intentFilter.AddAction(BluetoothAdapter.ActionRequestEnable);


        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.RegisterReceiver(this, _intentFilter);
    }


    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            BluetoothDevice item = null;
            string action = intent.Action;

            switch (action)
            {

                case BluetoothDevice.ActionPairingRequest:

                try
                {
                    //You can set device pin by default to avoid asking.

                    int pin = intent.GetIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraPairingKey, 1234);
                    _bluetoothDevice.SetPin(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pin.ToString()));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
                    break;


                case BluetoothDevice.ActionBondStateChanged:
                    break;

                case BluetoothDevice.ActionFound:
                    //Bluetooth device found

                    /*/
                    / Here you can make a list for preparing popup
                    /*/
                    break;

                case BluetoothDevice.ActionNameChanged:

                    break;


                case BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished:
                    //Occurs when scan is finished

                    /*/
                    / Launch desired popup 
                    /*/
                    break;

                case BluetoothDevice.ActionAclConnected:
                    //Bluettoth device is connected
                    break;

                case BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected:
                    //Device is disconnected
                    break;

                case BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnectRequested:
                    break;
        }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteException(ex);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }




}
```